# Axes of symmetry in convex polygons

Tags: geometry, symmetry, polygons

A regular $n$-gon has $n$ axes of symmetry. I was wondering about necessary and sufficient conditions on the polygon for the converse to be true. That is, what kind of shape would I need such that I can say "This has $n$ axes of symmetry, therefore it is a regular $n$-gon."

At first I thought convexity was sufficient, but this isn't true, since a rhombus has $2$ axes of symmetry and it is certainly not a "regular $2$-gon", although there is no such thing as a $2$-gon, so maybe convexity is sufficient with the assumption that $n\geq 3$. Convexity is certainly necessary, since a $5$ pointed star has $5$ axes of symmetry and is not a regular pentagon.

Does anyone have any insight into this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a polygon whose sides have alternating lengths $a$, $b$, $a$, $b,\ldots$ but is nice and symmetric. Here's a concrete example: the octagon with vertices $(\pm2,\pm1)$ and $(\pm1,\pm2)$.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the question before I realised there was an answer. This is helpful though, it suggests that what I'm looking for doesn't exist. It may be the case that the statement I'm looking for is "a regular polygon with $n$ axes of symmetry is a regular $n$-gon", which doesn't seem as interesting.

Comment: @IAlreadyHaveAKey With $n$ axes of symmetry, the symmetry group is the usual $D_n$, so picking a finite set of points invariant under $D_n$ and taking their convex hull gives a polygon with symmetry group $D_n$ (or possibly larger).